# Oracle : ORA-04091: table AVIS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

So, I'm a french student in IT, I've got this work like 4 weeks before, and I really can't get around this problem (I mainly worked on PostGRE and it's way different for me).

I've got those two tables :
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRCyh.png)

To resume, I've got one table LIVRES (which is book in French), where there's two attributes :

-"refl", the primary key,

-"note_moy", a calculated attribute, later on that.

And a table AVIS (Rating I guess) with :

-"refl" as part Primary key (the other part is irrelevant), and foreign key references to LIVRES

-"note", with is rating from 0 to 20.

So the idea, is that "note_moy" on LIVRES is the average of all "note" ON AVIS, where the LIVRES.refl = AVIS.refl. So a book has an average rating, and I needed to do a TRIGGER, so every time there's a UPDATE or INSERT successfull, I would use the procedure "Maj_note_moy", who take a "refl", make the AVG of "note" on AVIS, and update the "note_moy" on LIVRES with that AVG.

Here the procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE maj_note_moy(vrefl livres.refl%type) IS
v_note_moy livres.note_moy%type;
BEGIN
SELECT AVG(note) INTO v_note_moy 
FROM AVIS
WHERE refl = vrefl;
UPDATE Livres SET note_moy = v_note_moy WHERE refl = vrefl;
--RETURN v_note_moy;
END;
/
```

When I use it with a PLSQL block (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y1yE.png)), it works no problem.

Now, back to the trigger, I try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_note_moy
AFTER INSERT ON Avis 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Maj_note_moy(:new.refl);
END;
/
```

And here it is : "Oracle : ORA-04091: table AVIS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

I understand what's the problem is, that I trying to do a SELECT on the table AVIS while I insert something into it. But that's what I can't get, I want the trigger after my insert or update, so why is it an issue ? I'm pretty sure I do something like this on PostGRE, and it didn't cause any problems.

So I check, I do saw the COMPOUND TRIGGER, but I really don't understand how it works, nor if it's relevant for my problem.

Comment: First of all it is a bad idea to store the data redundantly. If you can select the average from Avis easily, why store it also in Livres? Just don't do it and the problem is solved. And if you want it for convenience,you can write a view that shows the Livres data along with the Avis average. If you think you must store this value, then indeed a compound trigger is the way to go. The alternative would be a mere after statement trigger, but then you would't know the Livre and would have to recalculate all livres. In a compound trigger you can remember the livres and only update those.

Answer (score 1):

As @ThorsetnKettner points out in the comments, storing data redundantly via a trigger is rarely a good architectural approach.  Embed the calculation in a view or even a materialized view and then you don't have to write code to maintain the data or debug issues when your code has bugs (and in a multi-user system, aggregate values maintained by triggers will almost always have bugs).

Since you're a student, though, I'm guessing that this is part of a homework assignment.  If so

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_note_moy
  AFTER INSERT ON Avis 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(note) 
    INTO :new.note_moy
    FROM AVIS
   WHERE refl = :new.refl;
END;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maj_note_moy(vrefl livres.refl%type) 
  RETURN livres.note_moy%type
IS
  v_note_moy livres.note_moy%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(note) INTO v_note_moy 
    FROM AVIS
   WHERE refl = vrefl;
  RETURN v_note_moy;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_note_moy
  AFTER INSERT ON Avis 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.note_moy := maj_note_moy( :new.refl );
END;
```

would avoid the mutating table exception without needing to use a compound trigger.

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_note_moy
  AFTER INSERT ON Avis 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.note_moy := maj_note_moy( :new.refl );
END;
`

:new.note_moy is it really possible, since it's a attribut on LIVRES and not AVIS ? :new means to me that it's from the new entree, but it doesnt in here

`code`